# Game Screeps - Using the lodash module

Tags: screeps

I'm playing Screeps (http://screeps.com) and I'm trying to use the lodash module for filtering my harvesters from the rest of the creeps. The code below should work but when I run it I get a `ReferenceError: _ is not defined at <main>:6:18`. Any idea of what's wrong?

```
var harvesters = _.filter(Game.creeps, {memory: 'harvester'});
if(_.size(harvesters) < 3 && Memory.creep_queue.length===0) {
     Memory.creep_queue.push('harvester') 
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using the lodash module, it's necessary to require it into a var like below in the beggining of the module and then it should work:

```
var _ = require('lodash');
```

Comment: It is no longer required to do this. lodash is included by default.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

You can write your code also in this way:

```
var harvesters = room.find(Game.creeps, {
    filter: {memory: 'harvester'}
});

if(harvesters.length < 3 && Memory.creep_queue.length === 0) {
     Memory.creep_queue.push('harvester');
}
```

Since 2014-12-01 it is not necessary to find `room` in a hacky way. Now there's a global function `Game.getRoom()`.

> **OLD FRAGMENT**: The only problem is to have `room` value, but you can get it from eg. `Game.spawns.Spawn1.room`.